# javascript - "then" executing before the loop completes in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

EDIT: changed the code as suggested by the answer, using promises. It prints before `Added all tags` and then the various `Found`

I have the following code to fill an array with some keys from Firebase:

```
var userTags = [];
var arrayPromises = [];
user_pref.once('value', function(preferenze){ 
preferenze.forEach(function(t){
  ref.once('value', function(tags){ 
  arrayPromises.push(arrayPromises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  tags.forEach(function (t1){
    if(t.key == t1.key){ 
    console.log("Found " + t1.key)

    }
    return false;

  })}));
})
return false;
})
})
Promise.all(arrayPromises).then(()=>{
console.log("Added all tags")

})
}
```

I've added the `then` clause to be sure I call the method `findPoiByTag`is called after I filled the array, but apparently the code inside `then` is executed before the rest. In fact, the message `lenght 2:` is printed before the other message `Lenght`, with the consequence that it first prints "0" and then it prints the correct lenght while filling the array.

EDIT: it prints the lenght of the array a number of time equal to the number of forEach iterations, so the `return false` statement does not break the loop.

I've always used this method to wait for the instructions to be finished, why now is not working? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

oh well i see now, the then function is after the push function not afther the forEach so you will have to do something like this

```
var arrayPromises = [] 
forEach( 
push( 
... 
generatePromise 
... 
).then( 
... 
promiseRecieved 
checkForAllPromisesRecieved(doTheThing)
... ) ) 

function doTheThing(){
   this.myTags = userTags; 
   console.log("Lenght 2: " + userTags.length) 
   this.findPoiByTag(this.myTags);
}
```

Comment: if I delete the "return false" it gives me an error, saying that I have to return a boolean.

Comment: I've used this code before, same as this, Firebase usage needs this construct. It doesn't normally stop when there a return false, since it requires it. Also, if it would really return after first iteration, then it would print just once the lenght of the array, instead it prints it for every iteration.

Comment: oh well i see now, the then function is after the push function not afther the forEach so you will have to do something like this

var arrayPromises = []
forEach(
push(
...
generatePromise
...
).then(
...
promiseRecieved
...
)
)
//after all promises 
this.myTags = userTags;
    console.log("Lenght 2: " + userTags.length)
    this.findPoiByTag(this.myTags);

Comment: i changed my anwer :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how to use promises, I've changed my code in the question to show you how I've used them since it doesn't work fine the way I did :\

Comment: the Promise object is for normal requests, firebase does it a little different i really havent used firebase before but i will post the docs link to promises if that helps

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions?hl=en

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately there is not my case in that docs ... I'll reformulate a new question explaining the problem in depth since now it is a whole new problem, anyway thank you a lot for your time!