# javascript - how to use promises in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

Lately I've been stuck with a problem that I don't know how to solve. I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775150/javascript-then-executing-before-the-loop-completes-in-firebase/47775453) question and after some efforts we've found that Firebase works differently with promises than normal requests, and I couldn't use them properly.
As explained in [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775150/javascript-then-executing-before-the-loop-completes-in-firebase/47775453), I'm filling an array with some informations from Firebase, and I need to call another method when I'm sure the array is filled, in other words when I'm sure the call to Firebase has finished.
This is my code as I'm using it now:

```
var user_pref = firebase.database().ref('/users/'+ self.api.email_id+'/preferenze/');
      var ref = firebase.database().ref('/tag/')
var userTags = [];
var self1 = self;
user_pref.once('value', function(preferenze) { 
  preferenze.forEach(function(t) {
    ref.once('value', function(tags) { 
      tags.forEach(function(t1) {
        if (t.key == t1.key) { 
          console.log("Found " + t1.key)
          userTags.push(t1.key)
        }
        return false;
      });
    })
    return false;
  });
}).then(a =>{
  await this.sleep(1000) //----> WORKAROUND
  console.log("Out")
  this.myTags = userTags
  this.findPoiByTag(this.myTags) //method I have to call when finished
})
```

I'm using this orrible workaround with sleep to be sure the code outside is executed after the one inside. Without that, it prints "Out" before and then all the "Found" in the loop. I've tried using it with promises in every way, but it still doesn't work. Having a look at the [docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions?hl=en) I couldn't find anything that would help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's indeed pretty bad.

This should be closer to what you need:

```
var userTags = [];
var self1 = self;
user_pref.once('value', function(preferenze) { 
  var promises = [];
  preferenze.forEach(function(t) {
    promises.push(ref.child(t.key).once('value'));
  });
  Promise.all(promises).then(function(snapshots) {
    snapshots.forEach(function(snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        userTags.push(snapshot.key);
      }
    });
  })
  this.myTags = userTags
  this.findPoiByTag(this.myTags) //method I have to call when finished
});
```

What this does differently:

1. It loads each preference key with a direct look (removing the need for a deeply nested loop that was loading way too much data).
2. It puts all load of the categories into an array of promises.
3. It then calls your function after all promises have resolved.

Comment: So the piece of code inside Promise.all(promises) etc. does the same thing as the check for equality I do in my code, in "t.key == t1.key" ? Because I don't understand where you are using the second database reference called "ref". I've modified the code to let you understand better. I'm using nested loop 'cause I have to check for quality between two nodes of the database.

Comment: You're loading the data multiple times and then doing a client-side comparison. This is wasteful. My code does a direct lookup of the exact key you're looking for and then uses `snapshot.exist()` to check if it got a result. Try `ref.child(t.key).once('value').then(function(s) { console.log(s.key); })` in a debugger to see how it works.

Comment: Ok but I dont' understand where you are doing the comparison between the keys. I'm doing a join between two different nodes of the database, to 
 get the data I need only if the keys I'm comparing are the same. I can't find this in your code. If I understood, you are simply pushing all the keys you are finding in the array of promises, then wait for them. Where's the part where you compare the keys from the nodes?

Comment: As far as I can see in your code, you're essentially just checking if `t.key` exists in the database. That means you don't need to compare keys, so my code prevents that.

Comment: I **am** using the `ref` in `promises.push(ref.child(t.key).once('value'))`.

Comment: Also, if I do like this `ref.child(t.key).once('value').then(function(s) { console.log(s.key); })` this printing is AFTER the printing I've added just before `userTags.push(snapshot.key); ` . Means that it doesn't wait for promises

Comment: That line was just to show you that you can simply look p the child for `t.key`. The code as I have it in my answer should work. Are you sure you copied it correctly? Can you possibly reproduce where you are stuck with my code in a jsbin, so we're both looking at the same thing?