# How to move Firebase relational queries server side

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, react-redux

This is my first project with Firebase, and I've created a relational data structure. Now I see why this isn't the best way to do things!

In this part of my app, users can add multiple items to an outfit - here's a diagram of the data structure/relationship I have in Firebase now.

[image]

I've included code from a Redux action creator in my React Native app. When a user edits an outfit - removing some items - this code:

1. takes an array with the new list of items from the client
2. compares this array with the current saved items server side
3. creates a new array of the diff (removed items)
4. loops through the `outfits` for each of those items, matching against the outfit being edited
5. removes references that match

This code works, but is pretty deeply nested and messy:

```
export const updateTagReferences = (localTags, outfitId) => {
    //localTags represents the new set of items from application state
    //outfitId is the uid for the outfit where those items appear
  const {currentUser} = firebase.auth();
  return dispatch => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/outfits/${outfitId}/taggedItems`)
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        var serverTags = snapshot.val();
            // Work out the diff (ie, which items have been removed locally)
        return _.differenceWith(serverTags, localTags, _.isEqual);
      })
      .then(toDelete => {
        toDelete.map(item => {
          firebase
            .database()
            .ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/items/${item.item.uid}/outfits`)
            .once('value')
            .then(snapshot => {
              var outfits = snapshot.val();
              for (var taggedItem in outfits) {
                if (outfits.hasOwnProperty(taggedItem)) {
                  var i = outfits[taggedItem];
                  return i.uid === outfitId
                    ? firebase
                        .database()
                        .ref(
                          `users/${currentUser.uid}/items/${item.item.uid}/outfits/${taggedItem}`,
                        )
                        .remove()
                    : null;
                }
              }
            });
        });
      })
      .then(console.log('Done'));
  };
};
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use Firebase promises to loop through the `outfits` nested in each item server side.

My issues are:

- I'm making lots of queries to Firebase, which isn't ideal
- `console.log('Done')` fires before `.remove()` - I need to follow up with a second action once this action completes

I've tried the following code, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795594/javascript-how-to-use-promises-in-firebase), but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
export const updateTagReferences = (localTags, outfitId) => {
  const {currentUser} = firebase.auth();
  return dispatch => {
    // Create a ref for the outfit the user is editing
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/outfits/${outfitId}/taggedItems`)
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        // Compare local (app state) with remote (Firebase) to work out which items have been removed
        var serverTags = snapshot.val();
        return _.differenceWith(serverTags, localTags, _.isEqual);
      })
      .then(toDelete => {
        var promises = [];
        // Create a ref for each item to delete
        toDelete.map(item => {
          firebase
            .database()
            .ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/items/${item.item.uid}/outfits`)
            .once('value')
            .then(snapshot => {
              var outfits = snapshot.val();
              for (var taggedItem in outfits) {
                // Loop through the outfits that item appears in
                if (outfits.hasOwnProperty(taggedItem)) {
                  var i = outfits[taggedItem];
                  // Match against the outfit the user is editing
                  return i.uid === outfitId
                    ? promises.push(
                        firebase
                          .database()
                          .ref(
                            `users/${currentUser.uid}/items/${item.item.uid}/outfits/${taggedItem}`,
                          )
                          // Remove the reference
                          .remove(),
                      )
                    : null;
                }
              }
            })
            // Execute all the promises, removing firebase references for each item removed locally
            .then(Promise.all(promises).then(console.log('Done')));
        });
      });
  };
};
```

I'm trying to make my code more efficient overall, so I can replicate it elsewhere in my project. I'd love an explanation of the best way to move this kind of query server side.

Currently, changing the whole data structure is out of scope (that's for next time!)

Thanks.

Comment: Try `return Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log('Done 1'));`

Comment: Also `promises.push()` returns the new length of the array, not the element that's just been added? Needs to be fixed.

Comment: Sorry - I’ve updated the first code block. I’d accidentally posted a previous version.

Comment: You need the `promises` array and `Promise.all(promises)` etc from the original code.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve with object `i` and its property `i.uid`. What is supposed to be assigned to `i.uid` and where does the value come from? And what is supposed to happen to `i`, does anything else depend on it?

Comment: In my database, each user has a list of items and a list of outfits. Once users tag an item in an outfit, 2 references are created - one in the outfit, one in the item. This code takes a list of items for a given outfit, and removes references from Firebase where necessary (ie where the user has made a change locally). i.uid refers to the UID for the outfit being referenced, which is the outfit being passed to the function. Because of how Firebase works, on the database side this UID is nestled within `item/outfits/uid/uid`. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Doesn't make complete sense without seeing an Entity-Relationship diagram. On the surface, you appear to have three one-to-many relationships but it's possible that at least some of those relationships are (or should be) many-to-many. For example, if a user can tag many `items`, and an `item` can be tagged by many `users` (which seems reasonable), then you would have a many-to-many relationship and the DB structure would need an intermediate Entity comprising two foreign keys; `user_` and `item_`.

Comment: Although it's not strictly necessary (because it's implied by the outfit<<items hierarchy), the intermediate Entity could also contain an `outfit_` foreign key. With that structure in place, deletions would be simple. Untagging an item would be a matter of finding and deleting an intermediate Entity tuple, and the (redundant) user-outfit relationship would also disappear. But this is all conjecture as the precise nature of the relationships is unclear.

Comment: I've added a diagram of the relation, and updated the code with better comments. I hope this gives you enough context to better help me out here. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Mmm, don't know how to read that. I was hoping for an [Entity Relationship Diagram](https://www.smartdraw.com/entity-relationship-diagram/).

Comment: Ah - I see. Apologies, I'm pretty new to databases. I've had a go at creating an entity relationship diagram. Hope that looks better! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes, much better but my problem now is that I need to challenge the E-R diagram, which you say is off limits.

Comment: Ah, well it’s not totally off limits. I was just trying to keep the scope of the question limited. I’d love to hear your thoughts on how it could be more efficient.

Comment: OK, so Items and Outfits have a many-to-many relationship and your representation of it is fine in an E-R(Semantic) diagram. However, in an E-R(Implementation) diargam (and in the implementation itself), each many-to-many relationship should be converted by the following rules; (1) split the link and insert an intermediate Entity between the two Entities; (2) reverse the crows-feet on the two links that connect the new Entity to the two original Entities. ...

Comment: ... The reason this is necessary is that an RDBMS can't directly implement many-to-many, only one-to-many (or one-to-one, which is a special case of one-to-many). By following the rules, you can add/remove relationships between Items and Outfits, independently of adding/removing Items and Outfits themselves and the danger of hanging references will be avoided.